# Simple counter increment in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, counter

In my controller, I want to count the number of bad attempts to login.

```
else
{
     // Increment counter by 1
     // check if counter == 3
     // ban user
     logonAttempt++;
     if (logonAttempt >= MAX_LOGON_ATTEMPT)
     {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "This account has been locked. Please contact the help desk for further support.");
     } else
     {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "You have entered an invalid username or password.");
     }
}
```

Every time the user clicks "submit" and the code enters into this else statement, the logonAttempt resets to 0.

Is there anyway to prevent it from resetting? for the users session?

Comment: Are you storing the loginAttempt variable back into the session?

Comment: Or are you actually using session at all?

Comment: I believe I am. If the user signs in successfully, 
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

Comment: you need to use HttpContext.Session to store any value over multiple requests but @aepelman's post is correct for auth

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding some stuff. 
You can count in the session, but the new architecture patterns tend to work as session less.
The lifecycle should be, request, instantiate something really small, respond, and then release the instance to start working lightweight.

One thing you can do is just update the cookie stored with the validation token or method you are using for login.
My advice is just to check this framework, really flexible, where all these concerns are already solved.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it in a way like this:

// my class

```
private static XDic<DateTime, XDic<string, int>> daily_reg_attemps = new XDic<DateTime,XDic<string, int>>(); 
const int limit = 20;

    public bool is_banned(string key,HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //handle attempt monitoring
        var today = DateTime.Today.Date;
        if (!daily_reg_attemps.ContainsKey(today))
            daily_reg_attemps.Add(today, new XDic<string, int>());
        var reg_attemps = daily_reg_attemps[today];

        //handle attempts
        var ip = GetClientIp(request);
        if (!reg_attemps.ContainsKey(ip)) reg_attemps.Add(ip, 0);
        if (!reg_attemps.ContainsKey(key)) reg_attemps.Add(key, 0);

        //prevent localhost
        if (!request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("localhost"))
        {
            reg_attemps[ip]++;
            reg_attemps[key]++;
        }

        return (reg_attemps[ip] > limit || reg_attemps[key] > limit);
    }
```

//my custom dictionary

```
public class XDic<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
   public virtual void Add(TKey key, TValue value, bool updateIfExist = true)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key parameter is Null.");
        }

        if (base.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (updateIfExist)
            {
                base[key] = value;
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException("Error")
            }
        }
        else {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
```